# Counting duplicate records disregarding NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

**Sample Data:**

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN3 | COLUMN4 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| A       | B       | C       | null    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| A       | B       | C       | D       |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| X       | Y       | null    | Z       |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| X       | Y       | Q       | Z       |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

**Expected result : 
    2**

**Explanation:**

I need to count the unique records in the above and the definition of that in this case is that ALL filled values in the record have to be the same, BUT if one record has a filled value and another one has a NULL in that same column it has to be considered as the same.

So in the above example the count would be 2 since for record 1 and 2 all the filled columns are the same and in column4 D has to compare to NULL as equal.
Anyone have some suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: I think the expected result will be {(A, B, C, D), (X, Y, Q, Z)}. He tries to retrieve duplicate tuples, dealing with NULL as a don't-care. @jarlh

Comment: Hey, most people here want sample table data (and the expected result) as formatted text, not images.

Comment: The expected result would be 2 in this case (i just have to be able to count at this moment)

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, postgres, oracle...?

Comment: SQL Server 2017 Management Studio

Comment: ROW_NUMBER, NOT EXISTS etc.

Comment: what would be the result if there is another row like (A, Y, Q, D), as you can see, the results already appear in previous rows?

Comment: Does your table have a primary key?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your table has a primary key called `id`, you could do this with `exists` and aggregation

```
select count(*) result
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1 from mytable t1 
    where 
        t1.id <> t.id 
        and t1.column1 = t.column1
        and t1.column2 = t.column2
        and t1.column3 = t.column3
        and (t1.column4 is null or t.column4 is null or t1.column4 = t.column4)
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e59155a437a0c08ef050e7a6b1933881)**:

```
| result |
| -----: |
|      2 |
```

Comment: @Richard_2413 . . . If you run this query with `select *` rather than `select count(*)` you will see what rows are being counted.  It is not doing what you want.  It is a subtle problem.  There is an example in the SQL Fiddle in my answer that enhances that data and demonstrates that it works.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: yes, our queries do not count the same thing, although for the given sample data we get the same result. It's not that clear what OP wants after all.

Comment: @Richard_2413: you might want to have a look at the below answer by GordonLinoff. It would be interesting to run both queries against a larger dataset of yours and see which (hopefully) provides the intended result.

Comment: @GMB: It goes wrong when there are multiple columns that can contain a NULL value. in the sample data above for example if on line 3 the value of column 4 would be W the answer needs to change to 1. This is giving me headaches :/

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with two different tables.
I used inner join and checked if table1.col1 is null then use table2.col1

Eg: select ISNULL(table1.Col1,table2.Col1) from table1 full outer join table2 ......so on

In case of same table u can apply join with different alias

Check if it works in your case

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct answer to this question is:

```
select count(*)
from mytable t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from mytable t2 
                  where t2.id < t1.id and
                        (t2.column1 = t1.column1 or t1.column1 is null or t2.column1 is null) and
                        (t2.column2 = t1.column2 or t1.column2 is null or t2.column2 is null) and
                        (t2.column3 = t1.column3 or t1.column3 is null or t2.column3 is null) and
                        (t2.column4 = t1.column4 or t1.column4 is null or t2.column4 is null) 
                 );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b9abcf505110fcf636df64bc339e8818) is a db<>fiddle.